# I am confused with simply how to solve local optimization problems of multiple variables on a curve.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

> For $f(x,y) = x^3 + x^2y - y^2 - 4y$,
> find and classify all critical points of $f$ on the line $y = x$.

My Attempt:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y) = 3x^2 + 2xy = 0 \implies x(3x + 2y) = 0 \implies x = 0,-4,1$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y) = x^2 - 2y - 4 = 0 \implies x^2 - 2y = 4 \implies y = -2,6,-3/2$$

So, the critical points are: $(0,-2), (-4,6), (1,-3/2)$

The first thing I thought was that $y = x$ was the domain of allowed critical points, but then that would mean that no critical points would work.

Next I thought we needed to plug in $x$ for $y$ in the partial derivatives to find the true critical points, but that didn't work either.

What is confusing to me is when I look at the answer key, it says the critical points are $(1,1)$ and $(-2/3,-2/3)$, but when I plug these points into the partial derivatives set equal to zero, neither of them satisfy the equations.

I know I am missing something here, but I just don't know what it is.

Answer (score 1):

The key point is that local extrema along a curve may not be local extrema when viewed from the entire domain. By setting both partials equal to zero, you're looking for points where the graph is locally flat in all directions, but really you want to find points where the part of the graph obtained by restricting $f$ to the curve $y=x$ is flat. One way to accomplish this is to parametrize the curve $y=x$ via the parametrization $(t,t)$, then the problem of optimizing on curves reduces optimizing the single-variable function $f(t,t) = 2t^3-t^2-4t$.